# Monitor packets when using soapUI

Tags: rest, web-services, soapui, wireshark, fiddler

I am using SOPAUI to access one of the rest services. I want to monitor the headers that are being sent to one of the downstream application. I tried using fiddler4. That is not solving my purpose.

Let me give an example of what i am trying to achieve

I access endpoint A by sending a JSON request (Application A). The application A internally connects to a different end point, B (Application B), to get the required response.

Is there any tool that i can make use of to see the raw request created for Application B with all the header information and the response application B sends to Application A.

Comment: Have you given TCPMON a try? https://ws.apache.org/tcpmon/tcpmontutorial.html

Comment: Configure Application A to use Fiddler as HTTP proxy.